# What is the overhead using serial type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I understand that for a table where there are many `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s is a better choice to use a `serial` type as `primary key`.

But, for a table with standard data (such as continents, countries, genders, options) where an `INSERT` takes place very rarely and `DELETE` almost never and any `INSERT` is done strictly by an "admin" is still the use of serial type a better choice?

What is the overhead of using a serial type (sequence)?

Tia

Answer (score 1):

Overhead is extremely small: one row entry in [pg_class system catalog](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-class.html). Starting from PostgreSQL 10 you may use ANSI SQL [IDENTITY columns](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/). The overhead is pretty the same, means there is no overhead at all.

Comment: Thanks. `IDENTITY` is more **elegant** way to declare **auto-increament columns**. Is there any way to use the same elegant syntax to share an `IDENTITY` between 2 or more tables (I mean without using the sequence syntax)?

Comment: No. `IDENTITY` is syntax sugar which produces some internal work. Thus if you need to share sequence between several tables, you should create it manually.

Answer (score 1):

`serial` is *not* a performance feature.

Its use is to automatically assign unique values to a column, usually as an artificial primary key.